# invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Pop' Code Bloks

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have an error when I compile this program I have an error at the line where I wrote //ERROR. I do not understand what is happening. 
On compilation I have this error:
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Pop'|
Thanks for your help, Carlos

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
/*******************************************************************************
Constroi array de estruturas inicial
*******************************************************************************/
void ConstroiEstruturaInicial(struct Pop *populacao, int *vetorOrdemEntrada){
for (int i=0; i<nrBlocos;i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<nrBlocos;j++){
        printf("j=%d \n",j);
        vetorOrdemEntrada[j]=999;
        }
     criaVetorOrdemEntrada(vetorOrdemEntrada);
     for (int k=0;k<nrBlocos;k++){
         populacao[i].PopVetorOrdem[k]=vetorOrdemEntrada[k];  //ERROR!
         printf("%d ",populacao[i].PopVetorOrdem[k]);
     }
     printf("\n");
   }
}

int main(void)
{
int nrBlocos .....is a global variable Example =20;
typedef struct Pop{
    char PopStrConcatenada[MAX1];
    int PopComprimento;      
    int PopVetorOrdem[75];   
    char PopStrComp[MAX1];          // String comprimida
    int PopQualidade;               // Comprimento da string comprimida
    float PopProporcialidade;       // Porporção da Qualidade no total;
}pop;
struct Pop populacao[nrBlocos];

int vectorOrdemDeEntrada[nrBlocos]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,.....,19};
/* Call function*/
ConstroiEstruturaInicial(populacao, vetorOrdemEntrada);
}
//On compilation I have this error:
//error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Pop'|
```

Comment: You need to define the type *before* you use it... the struct definition shouldn't be inside `main()`, but near the top of the file (or in a header file), before any code that may need it.

Comment: Move that `typedef struct Pop...` *out* of `main` into global id space, and *above* your implementation of `ConstroiEstruturaInicial`.

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri. I have spend few hours and I have not see the error!

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig. I have spend few hours and I have not see the error!